# How to access marionette router from view?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Since I am using require js to keep my code modularized, I want to be able to acess the router instance in my view.

```
window.appRouter = new Router({ controller: this.routerController });
```

Apparently, I don't want to use window but still make the router available across my app.

What could be the best practice or marionette way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may store router on Application instance.

For e.g you instance your Router on Application start:

```
onStart: function() {
    this.router = new Router({ controller: this.routerController });
}
```

Its common practice to store Application instance as global, in this case you can access router inst via `window`.

If you use Marionette.Module - you can access it via second argument in module callback:

```
MyApp.module("module", function(mod, app){
    //app.router
});
```

The final way i see is to put router in a separate module.

```
MyApp.module("router", function(mod, app){
    //var ctrl = { some: controller }
    app.router = new Router({ controller: ctr });
});
```

So in this case you may access router via `App.router` or App.module("router")

Comment: Or you could use require.js or browserify to fetch it. It's a bit cleaner than global var but really only makes sense if there's good reasons not to use the built-in module system.